# Sharelatex doesn't want to work with all packages

Tags: sharelatex, online

I have my project in GitHub. I want to keep the last version of it online. I found that "`https://www.sharelatex.com/github/repos...`" can help me. But today I've managed to install package `rmathbr`, which makes Russian rule of repeating math symbol on the next line become true (this is unique package, not present in default installations of TeX-packages).

But the online-compiler at www.sharelatex.com doesn't know anything about `rmathbr`.

So, now I see only this:

[image]

In log-file www.sharelatex.com gives, of course:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `rmathbr.sty' not
>   found.

The question is, how to correct this situation? Is it possible to have this work with sharelatex.com or is there another service to use for compiling GitHub-projects?

PS. Maybe it is simple question, but so far I can't succeed.

I know that sharelatex.com does not work with `picsin` package also.

If you wish to play with this package, GitHub and sharelatex.com with me, You can download it from my dropbox, for example here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4ifnzz9796g64x/rmathbr.sty?dl=0

Comment: Upload the package?

Comment: @cfr The question is how to upload this package to the sharelatex.com. I tried to upload this package to my project, and `\usepackage`,`\input`,`\include` - nothing works.

Comment: Check with the Sharelatex team on how to upload a package file. It should *sit* in the same directory as `main.tex`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Where did you find that? I can't find any reference or help about it. But your comment really has helped me. It works! Thanks!

Comment: That is common LaTeX knowledge, explained in every introductory material. ShareLaTeX hides the fact, that you need to know one or two bits about LaTeX.

Comment: @Johannes_B Your last comment was something like humiliation for me. But, nevermind.

Comment: Everybody starts somewhere.  I certainly have had the chance to flaunt my own globally large store of ignorance here.  And since this is a question answer site, not knowing something is no big deal.

Comment: Dida, my comment wasn't meant to humiliate you. I am unhappy with the way the online compilers mislead starters in tricking them to think no LaTeX knowledge is needed. Even the documentation for starters on ShareLaTeX is faulty at pieces.

Comment: @Johannes_B And I am unhappy the way the LaTeX manuals mislead starters in tricking them to think no TeX knowledge is needed. The result is: cca 90 % questions here.

Comment: @wipet I think if people would read LaTeX introductory material and documentattion, 90 % of the question would not exist. The rest would be a bit harder nuts, including some TeX. People just don't read anymore, it seems.

Comment: @wipet I had to learn the importance of TeX, but only after being "tricked" into thinking LyX would suffice, and then after that, I thought only LaTeX was needed, to the realization that the more TeX you know, the better off you are.  But it took a lot of stumbling around.

Answer (score 2):

When you open your document on ShareLaTeX you should see something like the following:

[image]

Click the image with an uparrow that's circled in blue. A window will pop up and allow you to upload files from your local hard drive. Select the `rmathbr.sty` and upload. Voila

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have no project in ShareLatex. 

I have project in GitHub. 

I have never used this online service in this way. 

But thanks to you. Knoweledge that file of package should be in the same folder as main.tex was really helpful for me.